# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:

Tags: c#, asp.net, cross-domain

I has Web Method in a server.  I has set the cross origin in the WebApiConfig.cs file as below

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
        // Web API configuration and services
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods:   
 "*");
 config.EnableCors(cors);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

in my webmethod.cs, I also has enable the cross origin as below

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "http://192.168.2.8:96", headers: "*", methods: 
   "*", exposedHeaders: "X-Custom-Header")]
   public partial class WebMethod : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
   }
```

At client side, I call the webmethod using the code below

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://192.168.2.8:96/WebMethod.aspx/test",
            data: "{'sLat': '" + lat + "', 'sLng': '" + lng + "', 'Name' : '" + name + "', 'Address': '" + addr + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.d == true) {
                    alert("Success Check In");
                }
                else {
                    alert("error");
                }
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {                    
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        })
```

When I run the system and call the webmethod, in the browser console, it show me "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I'm using IIS7, .net framework 4.5

Anything I has miss out in setting?
Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: You got your attribute values backwards... Origin is origin, not target.

Comment: sorry...not get your means...do you means the origin in the EnableCors is not correct?  mind to explain.  Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.cors.enablecorsattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Hi Alexei, I has try to change the origin to http://localhost:63631, the problem still there.